# Not-so-mobile-friendly bootstrap page

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm having some difficulty getting a simple cutout bootstrap page to be mobile friendly. I've made sites using bootstrap before, but for whatever reason I can't quite tell what I'm doing wrong here. Any advice to make this more mobile friendly would be appreciated. Thanks!

Ultimately, my issue is that the page is rendering as if it were on a desktop/laptop when on a mobile device. Rescaling in browser gets closer, but when testing with real devices, it's not very mobile friendly (rendering a tiny square at the top of the screen.)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title></title>
    <script src=
    "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.min.js">
    </script>
    <script src=
    "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <link href=
    "https://cdn.rawgit.com/twbs/bootstrap/v4-dev/dist/css/bootstrap.css"
    rel="stylesheet">
    <script src=
    "https://cdn.rawgit.com/twbs/bootstrap/v4-dev/dist/js/bootstrap.js">
    </script>
    <style>
    .bodyStyle {
        background-color: black;
        color: white;
    }

    .contentBody {
        background-color: rgba(15,15,15,.8);
        margin-top: 75px;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 200px 2px rgba(0,0,0,1);
        border: solid rgba(0,0,0,.3) 1px;

    }

    .indent {
        margin-left: 10px;
    }

    body {
        background-image: url();
        background-size: cover;
        min-height:100vh;
        min-width:100vw;
    }



    .table-hover > tbody :hover {
        color: black !important;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body class="container bodyStyle">
    <form class="col-xs-12 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 contentBody">
            <br>
            <h2></h2>
            <h6></h6>
            <div data-ng-controller="" style="height:100%; width:100%">
                    <h6>Blah Blah Blah, content.<br>
                    <br></h6>
                    <div>
                            <h6></h6>
                            <div class="">
                                    <h6></h6>
                                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                                            <h6><input class=
                                            "btn btn-info-outline" type=
                                            "button" value="7"></h6>
                                            <div class=
                                            "col-xs-6 input-group" style=
                                            "float:right">
                                                    <h6><input class=
                                                    "form-control col-xs-8"
                                                    style=" float: left;"
                                                    type="text">
                                                    <span class=
                                                    "input-group-btn"><input class="btn btn-info-outline"
                                                    style="float:left;"
                                                    type="button" value=
                                                    "8"></span><br>
                                                    <br></h6>
                                                    <div class=
                                                    "col-xs-12 input-group">
                                                    <h6>
                                                            <input class="form-control col-xs-6"
                                                            placeholder=""
                                                            type=
                                                            "text"></h6>
                                                            <div class=
                                                            "input-group-btn"
                                                            style=
                                                            "min-width:300px;">
                                                            <h6>
                                                            <select class="form-control">
                                                                    <option style="color:black; min-height: 25px;"
                                                                            value="">
                                                                            </option>
                                                                    </select></h6>
                                                                    <div>
                                                                            <h6>
                                                                            </h6>
                                                                            <div>
                                                                            <h6>
                                                                                    <br>
                                                                                    </h6>
                                                                            </div>
                                                                    </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                    </div>
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
                            </div>
                    </div>
            </div>...
            <table class="table table-hover"></table>
            <div>
                    <br>
                    <div>
                            <div class="col-xs-2">
                                    <div>
                                            <img src=""> <a><br></a>
                                    </div>
                            </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="pull-right">
                            <input class="btn btn-info-outline" type=
                            "button" value="k">
                    </div><br>
                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                            <h2></h2><br>
                            <br>
                            <br>
                            <br>
                            <div>
                                    <b><br>
                                    <i></i></b>
                                    <div class="indent">
                                            <b><i></i></b>
                                    </div>
                            </div><b><br>
                            <span></span><br>
                            <span></span></b>
                    </div><b></b>
                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                            <b><img src="" style="max-height:200px;"></b>
                    </div><b></b>
            </div>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Please paste code directly in the post, rather than using a PasteBin link, and provide a JSFiddle (or suitable alternative) to illustrate your problem. Just saying "it doesn't work" isn't a sufficient question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [the starter template](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/introduction/#starter-template).

You omitted the meta viewport data, so mobile browsers are assuming you aren't trying to be mobile friendly and are scaling as if it were a desktop design.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
```